# Unable to send a request to a Server hosted on Render from Netlify

Tags: reactjs, node.js, deployment, render, netlify

I am encountering an issue with my deployed apps on different platforms. Here are the links to the sites where I have deployed my applications:

```
//Code:
Netlify: https://65302a29c2feb54008178e54--charming-chaja-7d8889.netlify.app/
Render: https://youtube-server-eg1i.onrender.com/
GitHub: https://github.com/NeihlalremGuite/youtube-clone
```

To provide more context, I have tested the application in two scenarios:

Local Development: When hosting the front-end locally on my system, it's able to send requests to the Render server without any issues.

Netlify Deployment: However, when I deploy the front-end on Netlify, I encounter this problem, and the requests to the Render server fail.

Here's an image illustrating the issue:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWTgF.png)

Any help or insights regarding why the requests aren't working on Netlify but work when hosted locally would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any Netlify configuration setup for routing?
can you create a file named `_redirects` in the public folder and this to it:
`/* /index.html 200`

Save and redeploy.

Comment: I tried adding the above file inside public folder. After redeploying, nothing renders on my screen and I am getting this error.

react-dom.production.min.js:189 TypeError: a.map is not a function
    at zm (Home.jsx:28:21)
 
du @ react-dom.production.min.js:189

Comment: humm, that's weird. I checked your website and it seems to return not found when requesting pages. I thought it could be because of the redirects not being handled correctly. Your github repo seems to be private so it is hard to debug and know the root cause.

Comment: Sorry, made the repo public. Please help me if you can identify the issue